# Are questions about wildlife and dealing with them around your home on-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question (probably 2) about dealing with wildlife (hawks, specifically) and interacting with them around my home.

My first question deals with a fresh hawk kill in my backyard - if I want to keep them around (for rodent control) should I leave the kill or clean it up?

And the follow up (pending answers to the first question) would be about safely cleaning it up so I minimize the spread of disease.

A separate 3rd question deals with the rabbit itself.  I have the very strong feeling the rabbit is female who has spent time in our yard in the past years.  Once or twice in the last few years, I have stumbled across the nest.  Since I'm guessing this is the same rabbit, I am guessing the nest is somewhere in the yard.  If I find it, is there anything that I can/should do to save the bunnies?

Are any of questions, or all on-topic here?  Or do I need to find another SE site?  The on-topic page only says:

> The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange is for people who love outdoor activities, excursions, and outdoorsmanship.

so that does't really help me understand whether questions of this sort would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say your questions are OK for the main site.