# Questions about wildlife support on The Great Outdoors

Tags: discussion, scope

I am pretty active on Pets.se, answering questions about helping wildlife are out of scope there.  A couple of days ago we got the question [How to help a wild baby parrot who cannot fly?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20404/how-to-help-a-wild-baby-parrot-who-cannot-fly) I did post answer about if it was an escaped pet, but turns out it is really a wild bird.

I suggested the user also post it at [biology, which they did and it was closed.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73511/how-to-help-a-wild-baby-parrot-who-cannot-fly)

We now have a new question about wildlife [Safety of red ear turtle eggs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20425/safety-of-red-ear-turtle-eggs)

Does TGO want to be the stackexchange home for questions about supporting wildlife?

If so I will suggest to the moderators of Pets.se and Biology.se that they migrate these questions to TGO.se

We have [Are questions about wildlife and dealing with them around your home on-topic](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/619/are-questions-about-wildlife-and-dealing-with-them-around-your-home-on-topic) which implies they are probably ok here.

Comment: We do take a lot of wildlife related questions. There are tons of questions on bears and elephants and birds and bees and whatnot. As long as they are not domesticated the questions should be on topic.

Comment: Yes please James Jenkins! Thanks to @rory alsop, our new on-topic page includes "bird and animal watching and behavior."  I think you're correct that there isn't any other good place for questions like that, and if we have people coming here who are already interested in wildlife, support questions would be perfect. I'm on a barely-functioning computer so I can't do much research, but I think we have more examples to add to yours, and Charlie Brumbaugh's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think they would be on topic, we already have a few similar questions,

- [Foxes in the living room - what causes this behavior?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14972/foxes-in-the-living-room-what-causes-this-behavior)
- [How to tell the difference between bobcats and house cats?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/how-to-tell-the-difference-between-bobcats-and-house-cats/19375#19375)
- [Is there scientific evidence of bobcats breeding with house cats?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19367/is-there-scientific-evidence-of-bobcats-breeding-with-house-cats/19388#19388)
- [Could this year's unusual warmth harm turtles?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15420/could-this-years-unusual-warmth-harm-turtles)
- [How would you help a snapping turtle cross the road?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14121/how-would-you-help-a-snapping-turtle-cross-the-road)
- [Why should lights be turned off on beaches where turtles breed?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16568/why-should-lights-be-turned-off-on-beaches-where-turtles-breed)

As long as the lines stays

- Domestic -> Pets
- Wild -> here

I think we are fine.

[image]

Comment: We also have a question about humanely keeping mice outside.  So I agree that helping wild animals belongs here.

Comment: A cougar in a bathtub?  That question would be inscope at Pets.

Comment: What happened to this cat?  You had her/his picture on Chat.  Was she lost, if so was she found, or it she now yours?

Comment: @ab2 https://awesomejelly.com/mountain-lion-bath/

Comment: OK, I fell for it.  If I tried that with my 14 pound cat, I'd wind up in the ER!   And the mountain lion had his claws and teeth, as can be seen in the video of his opening a box.  The video of him in a dog-obedience class dressed in a coat against the cold is very unpleasant.

Comment: Charlie, obviously I've upvoted this question and answer. I'm curious about the formula for drawing the line. If a question is asked from the opposite perspective, would the appropriate site change? For instance,  would "Is there scientific evidence of house cats breeding with bobcats?" belong on Pets?  Maybe someone would be concerned that letting their cat out at night would create a situation where it might breed with a bobcat so they're seeking information.

Comment: As with anything, both communities would need to be respected. I plan to ask James Jenkins the same thing anyway because he'll have a bigger role as far as mod discussions concerning migration. I was just asking your opinion based on your diagram, for clarity's sake, especially for people who don't know us well.

Comment: @Sue I think that much like bicycles some questions may be in scope at either site.  When you are on TGO, the question is not about the scope of other sites, only the scope of TGO matters.  If you think it is not in scope at TGO, but might be at Pets then suggest a migration. If it is in scope at both, it can stay where it was posted.  Many of the questions [tagged dog](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs) are in scope at Pets, but their is no reason for them to migrated, as they are fine here.

Comment: @Sue Its probably sin't worth worry exactly where the line is, Pets.SE doesn't want some questions and we will take them.